# How to write a function returns first which is not null, otherwise null

Tags: java, function

How to write the following function:

```
public Object getFirstNotNull(Object... objects){
    //return first that is not null
    //otherwise return null
}
```

Is there a way any other way unless `if-else-if` for all `Object`s?

Comment: You could use a loop?

Comment: what's the point of this?

Comment: Note that if you have Apache Commons you can use `ObjectUtils.firstNonNull`.

Answer (score 4):

Just do a for-loop and return when a non-null object is found.

```
for (Object obj : objects) {
    if (obj != null) {
        return obj;
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Isn't he trying to avoid `if` statements?

Comment: @I.K. I believe OP meant avoiding if statements to check each object.

Comment: return null at the end (didn't downvote).

Answer (score 4):

In Java 8 you can do

```
public static <T> T getFirst(T... ts) {
    return Stream.of(ts).filter(Objects::nonNull).findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: `.filter(Objects::nonNull)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use a for loop as follow:

```
public Object getFirstNotNull(Object... objects){
  for(Object obj:objects){
     if (obj != null) {
       return obj;
     }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: What does this answer add to the one already present since 4 minutes ?

Comment: I added it with mobile device. So when I started writing answer there was no answer. . .

Comment: @Jean-François Savard: the `return null;` statement, for example.